# Python Tornado - Confused how to convert a blocking function into a non-blocking function

Tags: python, tornado

Suppose I have a long running function:

```
def long_running_function():
    result_future = Future()
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(500000):
        result += i
    result_future.set_result(result)
    return result_future
```

I have a get function in a handler that prints the user with the above result of a for loop that adds all the number in the xrange:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    print "start"

    self.future = long_running_function()
    message = yield self.future
    self.write(str(message))

    print "end"
```

If I run the above code on two web browsers simultaneously, I get:

start

end

start

end

Which seems to be blocking. From my understanding, the `@gen.coroutine` and the `yield` statement does not block the IOLoop in the get function, however, if any functions that is inside the co-routine that is blocking, then it blocks the IOLoop.

Hence the other thing I did is to turn the `long_running_function` into a callback, and using the `yield gen.Task` instead.

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    print "start"

    self.future = self.long_running_function
    message = yield gen.Task(self.future, None)
    self.write(str(message))

    print "end"

def long_running_function(self, arguments, callback):
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(50000000):
        result += i
    return callback(result)
```

This doesn't cut too, it gives me:

start

end

start

end

I can use threads to execute those in parallel, but it doesn't seem the way to go, because I might be opening a lot of threads, and according to Tornado's user guide, it may be expensive.

How do people write async libraries for Tornado?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the blocking function is CPU-bound (as your for/xrange example is), then threads (or processes) are the only way to make it non-blocking. Creating a thread per incoming request is expensive, but making a small ThreadPoolExecutor to handle all CPU-bound operations is not.

To make a function non-blocking without using threads, the function must be *event-driven*: it must be waiting on some external event (such as network I/O) so that it can be awoken when that event occurs.

Comment: I think you are right, but the [Calling-blocking-functions](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#calling-blocking-functions) don't mention the CPU-bound or event-driven, it just say: "The simplest way to call a blocking function from a coroutine is to use a ThreadPoolExecutor, which returns Futures that are compatible with coroutines"

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently struggling to add a web interface for my simulation program using Tornado and its WebSocket function.
My simulation program is computationally intensive, i.e., CPU-bound task as said by @ben-darnell , which should be implemented using another **thread** or **process**.

After many investigations, I *think* these resources may be helpful:

- [Tornado blocking asynchronous requests - Answer by @koblas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13051972/4856091)
- [Trying to call a long blocking function in tornado in a non blocking way](https://gist.github.com/simplyvikram/6997323)

I'm doing the similar implementation now, and will update this answer when I have more progress :)