# bottleneck in python tornado websocket server

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, tornado

I have a websocket server written in python tornado. the server will receive many connections from clients and as you know, we have `on_message` function that is fired when a websocket message is received. so, here is my question that if a message(say request from client) need 5 sec to be processed then when the server is processing some request, the server goes in blocking mode and can't accept or receive more connection or data. after some research i figure out that `Asyncio` can resolve my problem but i don't now know to use it. so, how do i call `process` method to avoid blocking?
following is my code:

```
class WavesClient(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
    def open(self):
        print("New client connected")

   def on_message(self, message):
        self.process(message)

   def on_close(self):
        print("Client disconnected")
   def process(self,message):
        #it takes 5 sec to complete
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tornado - Confused how to convert a blocking function into a non-blocking function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148713/python-tornado-confused-how-to-convert-a-blocking-function-into-a-non-blocking)

Comment: anyway i didn't get my answer

Comment: You asked a similar question a while back. And I answered it, and you accepted that answer. Basically, the solution was to run the blocking code in a separate thread. But it seems that you've deleted your old question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use tornado primarily to host my webapps, therefore I can tell you if any part of your code in tornado is blocking, the whole server will block.

Now to your code:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def on_message(self, message):
    process_results = yield self.process(message)
    self.write_message(process_results)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def process(self, message):
    # a long process, this is the equivalent of time.sleep(2) which is blocking
    yield tornado.gen.sleep(2)
    return 'finished'
```

With `tornado` you have to `yield` from a function to get the return value.
Also, if your function is yielding, you must wrap it using the `tornado.gen.coroutine` decorator

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148713/python-tornado-confused-how-to-convert-a-blocking-function-into-a-non-blocking) is similar to yours. And the answer is informative as well.

Comment: but, what if i want to use a function instead of `tornado.gen.sleep(2)`, for example mysql queries, i just tested a non-async function and it blocked. i just want the application server response to other clients while a client request is processing

Comment: In tornado, you are highly advised to write asynchronous functions, otherwise it will block. For mysql, use [an async driver to peform queries](https://github.com/PyMySQL/Tornado-MySQL), see the link for examples.