# Tornado blocking other request or the ioloop

Tags: vuejs2, tornado

Problem:
Why can't I call others request

[image]

Goal:
Wanted to call other services even if the previous one is still on process

[image]

I already tried this 
[tornado-blocking-asynchronous-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051591/tornado-blocking-asynchronous-requests) but still blocks the other request

Main handler

```py
class Main(APIUserAuth):
    @gen.coroutine
        def post(self):
            hotelId=self.get_argument('code',False)
            try:
                if not hotelId:
                    raise Error('Hotel ID is not defined')
                params=escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
                result=yield Hotel.pricing(hotelId,params)
                self.write(result)
            except Error as e:
                self.write_wrong(str(e))
            except Exception as e:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                self.write_wrong()
            finally:
                self.finish()
```

Hotel.py

```py
@coroutine
def pricing(hotelId,request):
    params=parseParam(request)
    http_client=AsyncHTTPClient()
    url=URL+'/price'
    request=tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=url, method='POST',headers=HEADERS, body=json.dumps(params), connect_timeout=500, request_timeout=500)
    response= yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
    raise Return(response.body)
```

I wan't to call other request while the other 10 request are still on process.
But why is that the other can still process the new request while the other is on process?
Is having simultaneous  10 requests is too much to handle?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yVR8eNw.png]

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: In that case I think the code is correctly non blocking. Where is the problem ? Also, you don't need to wrap your http request within a Task, you can yield it directly like this: `yield http_client.fetch(request)`

Comment: Right now, I still don't know why is the other requests blocks, other article says that its the browser limitation that a concurrent request on the same url will block the other request.